# Forward http requests based on data from the request body

Tags: java, spring, servlets, routes, microservices

I have a service with many controller methods. My task is to "split" this service into microservices.

The microservices themselves will be deployed on other machines. Nginx redirect by location.

The main problem is that there is one location,  `http://mydomain/myservice/srv/data` that receives different types of requests.

And the logic after is called based on the value in the a field in the request body.

For example, two requests:

- `<request type="getname" val="1"/>`
- `<request type="balance" val="1"/>`

The first request must be forwarded on `http://mydomain/myservice1/data/name` and the second on `http://mydomain/myservice2/data/balance`

**Question**: Are there any libraries for such purposes?

**UPD**: I am writing simple jar based on RouteLocator (spring cloud); is there perhaps another way of doing this? Spring cloud not is the stack we're familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look to [spring integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration), it implements most of the [enterprise integration patterns](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/), including [content based routing](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ContentBasedRouter.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach of proxying the request based on different request types in the body is not a good way to proxy. The URI ultimately should be responsible for what kind of request it is serving and response it should be responding to.

The client has all the necessary information on the request type and therefore where to send the request. From that fact, I would refactor the resource that you have to different resources that handles the different request types and determine an explicit schema for the payloads for each one.

To summarize, the implementation would look like the following:

- Refactor server logic for different types of requests to their own resource URIs
- Move the logic of where to send the request into the client, perhaps utilizing something like a factory pattern

Comment: you're right. But i can't do that. URI should stay(((